# Eclipse (C++) crash Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I found a related problem here: how to fix “Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled” error while running java and here: Eclipse crashing on startup and here: Eclipse continue crash.

The solutions doesnt work for my problem:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f235f554fe0, pid=5347, tid=139790954133248
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b32) (build 1.7.0_65-b32)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.3
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libglib-2.0.so.0+0x38fe0]  g_str_hash+0x0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable coredumping,        try     "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

The Crash happens, when I want to open the slide: Windows/Breakingpoint Types. At the moment I hit the slide with my Mouse, ecipse tries to open the slide (witch is empty) and crashes.
Furthermore I am not able to toogle BreakingPoints in my code, the option under /Run is greyed out. Shift+Contro+B doesn"t work either.

I tried:
Reinstallation of eclipse,
Adding the lines to the config.ini (seperatly)

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
 org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

I am Using:
Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800
Ubuntu 14.04

Thank you for reading.

`

Answer (score 0):

SIGSEV related with segmentation fault because of array boundaries,invalid memory addresses.

Solutions:

- re-install eclipse first.
- if not works then re-install java with eclipse.

**OR**

Add `-XX:LoopUnrollLimit=1` as an argument.

Reference : [Enterprise Software Development : Don't use JAVA-7](http://blog.eisele.net/2011/07/dont-use-java-7-are-you-kidding-me.html)